# MySQL Statement SUM only when

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with my mysql statement.

This is my table "cars":

```
| Manufact | Model  |
---------------------
| Audi     | 2      |
| Audi     | 2      |
| Audi     | 4      |
| Audi     | 4      |
| Audi     | 8      |
| Audi     | 8      |
| Audi     | 8      |
```

I want to use `SUM()`.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(model) as number
FROM
    cars
```

BUT I don't want to SUM the eights, just only one time! I want to get the number: 20 (2+2+4+4+8)!

Does it work?

Comment: SELECT SUM(DISTINCT model) AS number FROM cars; would give you (2 + 4 + 8)
What distinguishes the 2's and 4's from the 8's?

Comment: is there any logic connected to only one 8?

Comment: I don't think this is to be done at sql statement. You should select * and get result in php (associative/numeric array) and then filter it there.

Comment: Odd why someone would want the sum of all unique models... then a lot of model numbers are not numbers ;) This may work for Audi, but good luck with other makers.

Comment: Strange query, but if you know that there will be at least one row with 8 then you can just ignore all of them with a where clause and hard-code a single 8 into the query: `SELECT SUM(model) + 8 FROM cars WHERE model != 8;`

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT SUM(Model) + 8 FROM cars WHERE Model != 8;
// Result 20 (2+2+4+4+8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Manufact ='Audi'
```

This query will get you all the fields that have `manufact` field equal to Audi. If you want to do it for other marks you just remove the `where` clause.

After you execute your query and fetch the results, your results will be stored in an array named `$result` for the sake of the example.

Using `array_sum`  you can get the sum of the column you want like that:

```
$sum=array_sum['result]['Model']
echo $sum;
```

This will return `20` for this example or your general result if you use more records. 
Providing php solution as php is also tagged in your question

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select sum(number) from
(
    SELECT SUM(Model) as number FROM cars where Model != 8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(distinct Model) as number FROM cars where Model = 8
) as a
```

Comment: You are welcome! If you like it, you can accept it on the page by clicking on the check.

Answer (score 0):

An another way around, find the count group by `Manufact` and `Model` columns. Then use this as a sub-query and use a `CASE` expression

**Query**

```
select t.`Manufact`, 
sum(t.`Model` * (case t.`Model` when 8 then 1 else t.`model_count` end)) as `sum` from(
    select `Manufact`, `Model`, count(`Model`) as `model_count`
    from `cars`
    group by `Manufact`, `Model`
) t
group by t.`Manufact`;
```